# Spring Data JPA conditional entity join

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have unusual table setup that I want mapped in JPA. Here's a simplified example:

```
book
  company_id int
  book_id    int
  series_id  int

borrow
  company_id int
  book_id    int
  type       char
```

The problem is `borrow.book_id` is overloaded:

- If `borrow.type` is 'B', then `borrow.book_id == book.book_id`
- If `borrow.type` is 'S', then `borrow.book_id == book.series_id`

The relation is logically many `borrow` to one `book`. The immediate use case is: get all `borrow` rows given a list of `book`s. How should this be mapped in Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Are you using hibernate? Can hibernate propietary annotations be used?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I'm using Spring Data which seems to be using Hibernate by default. Not sure if Hibernate solutions will work in this setup, but I can try if you have one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like below in your Borrow entity mapping for Book -

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
    { @JoinColumnOrFormula(
        formula = @JoinFormula(
         value = "case " +
                 "when type == 'B' then book_id" +
                 "when type == 'S' then series_id " +
                 "else 1" +
                 "end", 
         referencedColumnName="book_id")) }
)
```

But you need to use the @ManyToOne annotation, even though this seems to be a @OneToOne association. The join formula won't work on OneToOne.
The downside with this approach would be, hibernate will unnecessarily create 2 joins which could be done using only 1 using a native query

If you are using spring data JPA then in your repository you could use method like -

```
@Query(value="sql stmt with conditional join and IN clause", nativeQuery = true)
List<Idto> findAllBorrowByBook(List<int> bookIds);
```

where "Idto" is an interface to map your resultset.